# Add object to an array in java mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I need to add an object to an array nested inside an other object in the most "best practice way".

The problem is that I don´t want to pull up the whole array from the db just to add an new object. There must be a better way to do this like just adding the new object to the array by a query?

As for now Im pulling up a Business object with included posts, adding the new post and then updating the Business object.

```
public interface BusinessRepository extends MongoRepository<Business, String> {

    @Query(value="{ 'id' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'posts' : 1 }")
    Business findOneIncludeOnlyPosts(String id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
@Query(value="{ SOME QUERY }")
void putPostInBusinessPosts(String id, Post post);
```

Is it possible or do I have to do it the more expensive way?

Using:

- spring-boot 1.3.5
- mongo-java-driver 3.2.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't achieve it using a `MongoRepository`. You will have to use `MongoTemplate` for that.

I don't regard it to be more expensive, but more verbose maybe.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

...

Update update = new Update();
update.addToSet("posts", post);
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(id);
template.updateFirst(Query.query(criteria), update, "business");
```

Assuming business is the name of the collection.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Is there a way I could use both MongoRepository and MongoTemplate trough the BusinessRepository interface?

Comment: You can do it by [having a custom repository implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and injecting a `MongoTemplate` into it

Comment: BTW, you should use `update.push` instead of `update.addToSet` if you want to trigger `$push`.

Comment: how will mongotemplate know that to which collection it need to save ?